# $\mathrm{Frac}(R)\subseteq\mathrm{Frac}(S)$ algebraic implies $R\subseteq S$ algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

EDIT: The matter is now resolved. Here is the statement and the proof.

Theorem: Let $R\subseteq S$ be an extension of integral domains and let $K\subseteq L$ be the corresponding fields of fractions. Then the extension $R\subseteq S$ is algebraic if and only if $K\subseteq L$ is algebraic.

Proof: Let $\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)$ be the algebraic closure of $R$ in $S$ and let $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ in $L$. By clearing denominators one can show that $$\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)=S\cap\mathrm{Alg}_K(L).$$
It is a standard fact that $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$ is a subfield of $L$. Then it follows from the equation that $\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)$ is a subring of $S$.

Now assume that $L$ is algebraic over $K$, i.e., that $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)=L$. It follows from the equation above that $\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)=S\cap L=S$ and hence $S$ is algebraic over $R$. Conversely, assume that $S$ is algebraic over $R$, i.e., that $\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)=S$, and consider any fraction $s_1/s_2\in L$. Since $S=\mathrm{Alg}_R(S)\subseteq\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$ we can think of $s_1$ and $s_2$ as elements of $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$. Then since $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$ is a subfield of $L$ we conclude that $s_1/s_2\in\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)$ and hence $\mathrm{Alg}_K(L)=L$ as desired. QED

For the rest of the details (and much more besides), see the following homework set with solutions:
http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/762sp16/762hw3sol.pdf

The relevant theorem is Problem 3(c).

Comment: What do you mean by an algebraic extension of rings?

Answer (score 2):

You get that for every $s\in S$ there is some $r\in R$ nonzero such that $rs$ is algebraic, by taking a common denominator $r$ of the coefficients in a polynomial equation for $s/1$ of degree $d$ and mutiplying throughout $r^d$.

It is false in general that the extension is integral. If you take say a root $z$ of $2X^2+1$ and adjoin it to $\Bbb Z$ then the extension obtained is not algebraic, but the extension of the field of fractions is algebraic.

Note that $2z$ is integral over $\Bbb Z$ in the example above.

Comment: The result is true. See the edit above.

Comment: @DrewArmstrong It seems we're using different definitions.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'd say that you have confounded "algebraic" with "integral".

Comment: @user26857 Yes, and my proof gives an affirmative answer then.